# how to avoid dialog skinning for certain android roms

Tags: android

In my app I have a custom dialog that works great on my stock gingerbread rom. I checked my app out on my friend's Atrix, and there is this extra border that looks to be consistent with the rest of the ui (sorry, dont have an Atrix here to test it out). The same thing happens when i use my app on a Droid 1 with stock froyo (theres a thicker, grey border). Is there a way to get rid of this?

Comment: My personnal advice is that you would kill the global user experience. I don't like applications skinning dialog, that makes really inconsistent UI, and getting the default ANdroid theme on Touchwizz or Motoblor would really annoy me! But don't take it bad, that's just my 2 cents, and my opinion!

Comment: @Profete162 I agree, but in this case its not as much a dialog as a skinned activity. Different enough not to seem like an inconsistency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to get rid of it is by overriding all the styles used in a dialog. Most of the time this is not necessary... a dialog on the Atrix will look like every other dialog on the Atrix, so the user doesn't really notice the difference. If you need a specific look to match your app, however, you need to style it.